# Looking for a font name typically used by sign shops

Tags: font-identification

[image: looking for this font that would be typically used by sign shops]

no luck on any automatic identifier sites

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

[BlowBrush Font](https://befonts.com/blowbrush-font.html) by Petar Acanskivia for befonts.com

[image: blowbrush]

Comment: Close but even if the italics was simulated, there are some definitive differences with some of the letters and texture. Possibly the base for a custom?

Comment: The characters are exactly the same, check the "U" end, the "LA" second option, the "T" and "F" vertical bottom. It is true is slanted and with some roughen borders. I will try to reproduce the question paragraph with the downloaded font.

Comment: The lower counterspace for the S specifically strikes me as more open. Looks like it might have been slightly extended to my eye on top of the added texture. The opening for the o seems a tad wider too.

Comment: The similarities are more than the differences: "R". Is a custom.

Comment: For sure, I think it's a great find! Just that OP should know that it's not just a matter of typing with the font.